# Max-width on an image within div

Tags: css

[This page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/events/2012/November/exclusive-wedding-fashion-show.html) has an image (the wedding dress) of 134 x 200px contained within a max-width div of 250px, but not sure best how to keep the original image sizes as opposed to the max-width div. Any ideas would be great as I've got stuck..

Comment: If you remove width=300 from the image's url, so that it becomes http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/includes/tn.asp?src=/LiveStorage/Uploads/image/CommunityArticles/DD8467A95E6A44539DE98EF34388142C%2Ejpg , it will switch back to 134px :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that a wordpress plugin was resizing that image, removing  `width=300` from the image's url did the trick